# Light Stream in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to make light stream that move from starting point to ending point in my game. so how to make light stream in cocos2d? and also want to do reflection on that light stream when it touches any surface. so what is the logic to make light stream and doing reflection? any Idea?

help me..

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question.  How are your in-game objects represented?  In other words, when you say you want the light to reflect when it touches any surface, what is your implementation of that surface? Are you using box2d, plain old sprites, or something else?

Comment: @spookyjon: first of all thanks for replying. It’s much about leading a light stream from one part of the room to the other part of the room, by turning  mirrors so the light itself change direction. so any idea about it? i am using simple cocos2d without any physics engine.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something simple like draw a line with ccdrawLine.  I've made lasers that simply draw a red line in this way.  The other way is to use a particle system/emitter. I use Particle Designer by 71squared but there are others out there.  Your options are endless in the ways you could make your beam look.  You just have to experiment with the settings to get your desired effect.

As to the reflection, I use box2d and a ray cast.  Have the ray cast start where the beam starts and then create a new beam on the first object it hits.

Here's a good tutorial on ray casts: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4653/intermediate-box2d-physics-forces-ray-casts-and-sensors

Comment: thanks for your answer. and how to do reflection when it touch any surface and also light stream will move to other direction according to surface? Any Idea or any logic?

Comment: If you follow the tutorial above and use box2d, the ray cast will give you a reference to the object being hit and also a normal. The law of reflection states 'the angle which the incident ray makes with the normal is equal to the angle which the reflected ray makes to the same normal' - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(physics)